# What are TQS, TQI and the TQP file extensions, and how can I open them?

Tags: file-extension

I'm using some old software on windows that looks like it accesses a database to serve up some questions. I'd like be able to access the database, but when I go into the data directory there are 3 files, named `questions.TQI`, `questions.TQS` and `questions.TQP`.

How can I open these files? Or are they somehow encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://filext.com/file-extension/TQI, the TQ_ file extensions are from the program [Insure++ by Parasoft](http://www.parasoft.com/product/insure/), which is a program that identifies C++ programming errors.

> Parasoft® Insure++® identifies difficult-to-track programming and memory-access errors, such as memory corruption, memory leaks, access outside of array bounds, invalid pointers, and more to ensure the integrity of your applications’ memory usage.

http://www.parasoft.com/product/insure/